# How to fix the Invalid environment variables error in T3 Stack

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, t3

I have downloaded the repo from Github and trying to run in my local machine.
Installed cross-env package.

----------- Error -----------------

ERROR (console/15295 on Narendras-MacBook-Air.local): ❌ Invalid environment variables:
DATABASE_URL: Required
NEXTAUTH_SECRET: Required
NEXTAUTH_URL: Required
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID: Required
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET: Required
AUTH0_ISSUER: Required

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install cross-env as Next.js automatically exposes environment variables to your server.

Make sure you have a `.env` file in your project's root:

```
DATABASE_URL=
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=
NEXTAUTH_URL=
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=
AUTH0_ISSUER=
```